# Can I power a router, some HDDs and a Raspberry Pi4 from the same power supply?

Tags: ups, ground-loop

I want to build a kind of NAS. See the plan in the picture below.

Is it ok to power all the devices from the same power supply? A friend of mine warned me that it might not work because of the so-called "ground loops" that can form in this situation.

What do you think?

[image]

Comment: I think it is OK, but any mistake in the wiring can blow up your devices, and do you trust you data with random buck modules powering a RasPi, or the RasPi being reliable? Would it be more cost effective to just buy a NAS and UPS?

Comment: I don't know how it would be like to buy a NAS, but it certainly wouldn't be as fun as if you make it yourself. What's wrong with the buck module, is not good to power a RasPi ?

Comment: Your picture shows the battery connected to the AC terminals of the supply but I'll guess that's just a diagram issue

Comment: Yes, it's just a block schematics, not a real life connection.

Comment: Please read the specs for the step-down module carefully. The one depicted most likely needs some sort of heatsink and fan to run at 3A, and it's power may not be clean/stable enough for RPi, which is somewhat picky (I would add a choke and electrolytic capacitors for at least 1000uFx6v with low ESR). Ground loops are not a problem as long as you are sure every ground is connected to a single terminal with adequate wires (the step-down depicted directly connects input ground to output ground). Please note that you need to connect the load to the output of your UPS and not to the power supply.

Comment: Can you recommend a good step-down (to power the Pi) ?

Comment: If everything is wired up correctly then yes. I did something similar for all my network gear and a nuc. The only thing to maybe caution is the suggestion for capacitors. I would also recommend a fuse block just in case. For the ups though mine kept overheating and they have lead acid which sucks. so i used that same ac/DC converter but connected to a small solar charge controller and a lifepo battery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be fine, with some caveats.

Your Pi Ethernet is transformer-isolated ("mag-coupled"); there is no direct ground connection through your Ethernet cable, and as such there can be no ground loop through your WiFi router. (This was [famously a problem](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/manufacturing-hiccup/) in the early Raspberry Pi days when the supplier sourced non-mag jacks in error, causing production delays.)

It is possible to have ground loops in your USB connection, but they're probably not going to cause a problem with the digital differential signal. USB ground loop isolators exist, but are typically only needed in audio applications.

Per Justme's warning in the comments, there's a possibility for Bad Things™ if one if your ground connections becomes loose over time, specifically, one of your peripherals may use a different ground return path, possibly sending too much current through that other peripheral. Screw terminals vibrate loose, loose wires get yanked, wires get broken. You could mitigate this by building your device into a metal chassis to provide a solid ground return path for everything.

At first glance, it looks like your UPS provides enough power (the USB hub won't draw nearly as much as its nameplate states, unless you try to use it as a power supply). Though the hub might actually be beefy enough to power an older-model Pi (IIRC the Pi model B used 5V 1A), which may be a way to eliminate the buck converter if you don't specifically need the Pi 4.

Comment: So do you think I could leave the USB Hub without external power supply, as the HDDs connected to it have their own power source ?

Comment: The USB hub probably needs its own power supply to work. But you can test this pretty easily.

Comment: Most PCs are not wired to their peripherals exactly like this. If they have separate isolated supplies, then they can't have ground loops either. This wiring diagram has ground loops everywhere because they share the same supply. It can still work though, but a loose ground wire somewhere and most of the current can flow via another device which may not handle the current.

Comment: I should have recognized that this was a DC UPS and not an AC UPS. I looked at the current and voltage ratings and everything... 

Thanks for the comment -- I edited the post.

Comment: @MattS The DC-DC converter I use to power the Raspberry has a small resistor connected between the input ground and the output ground. If my setup is like in the picture, won't the current consumed by the Pi flow to the main ground through the USB cable ?

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing wrong with this, it'll work fine. Small ground loops like these are only really relevant in analog audio equipment where every millivolt of interference counts. In digital systems, you *want* the grounds of all devices to be connected as well as possible.

Just don't use excessively thin wires. Look up wire gauge tables to find out how thick the wires have to be.